# New to React testing!! Getting an error in a simple React testing while using Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-testing-library

I'm just trying to learn/get a simple test to pass, so I can move onto some more advance testing.
I am trying to test if the heading in AddTodo matches the screen.getByText test.
It keeps throwing an error at line 7 the dispatch variable.

This is my AddTodo component

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addTodoAsync } from "../redux/todoSlice";

const AddTodo = () => {
const [value, setValue] = useState("");
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const onSubmit = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
dispatch(
  addTodoAsync({
  title: value,
 })
 );
  setValue("");
};



 return (
    <>
<heading>Add Todo</heading>
<div className="task-container">
  <input 
  type="text"
  placeholder="Add Todo"
  value={value}
  onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)}
  />
  <button onClick={onSubmit}>Add Todo</button>
</div>
</>
)
```

}

This is my testing code

```
import{ render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import AddTodo from './AddTodo';

test('if heading should render Add Todo', () => {
  render(<AddTodo />);
  const headingElement = screen.getByText('Add Todo');
  expect(headingElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});


This is the error I'm getting.

 ● if heading should render Add Todo

   could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>

     5 | const AddTodo = () => {
     6 |   const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  >  7 |   const dispatch = useDispatch();
       |                    ^
     8 |
     9 |   const onSubmit = (event) => {
    10 |     event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: the error message tells you what you need to do

Comment: I have Provider Wrapped in my index.js. Should I put it somewhere else?

Comment: You can either wrap your component with the Redux provider when rendering it in the test, e.g. `render(<Provider><AddTodo /></Provider>);` or mock the `useDispatch` function (using `jest.mock()` in case you are using jest, or by using sinonjs)